# How to use return value (str) of one activity as input a second activity in temporal python sdk?

Tags: python, temporal-workflow

I'm using the python sdk for https://temporal.io/.
I have a workflow that i'd like to execute two sequential activities.

1. Do X and return a filepath.
2. Do Y with data at that filepath.

```
@workflow.defn
class ScraperWorkflow:
    @workflow.run
    async def run(self, scraper_input: ScraperInput):
        
        scraper_result = await workflow.execute_activity(
            ercot_scraper, # activity that takes scraper_input and returns a path
            scraper_input,
        )
 
        extractor_result = await workflow.execute_activity(
            extract_activity,
            path_from_previous_activity,
        )
        return
```

How do i get path_from_previous_activity from the first activity?!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you mean with "path_from_previous_activity"?

You can pass the results of your fist activity as input to the second one. so can pass scraper_result as input to your extract_activity.

Answer (score 1):

If I’m understanding your question correctly it seems like you want both activities to run on the same machine.
That doesn’t happen by default with Temporal, each activity attempt may run on a different host.
You can leverage the sticky activity pattern to ensure activities run on the same host.

If you want to return a FilePath object, I believe that’s not serializable by default, there are different ways to handle this, the easiest of them being passing paths as strings.
I recommend returning a dataclass from the activity that contains both the result and the path so you can extend it if need be in a backwards compatible manner.

https://github.com/temporalio/samples-python/tree/main/activity_sticky_queues